# Does Spark Double on Muldrotha allow for additional plays from the graveyard?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

[Muldrotha, the Gravetide](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bMuldrotha%2c%20the%20Gravetide%5d) is on the battlefield:

> During each of your turns, you may play up to one permanent card of each permanent type from your graveyard.

I play [Spark Double](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSpark%20Double%5d):

> You may have Spark Double enter the battlefield as a copy of a creature or planeswalker you control, except it enters with an additional +1/+1 counter on it if it's a creature, it enters with an additional loyalty counter on it if it's a planeswalker, and it isn't legendary if that permanent is legendary.

Since I now have two creatures on the field that say I can play up to one permanent of any type from the graveyard, could I play up to two permanents of any type from my graveyard? Could I, for example, play two creatures instead of one during my turn? Or am I missing something?

The rulings only mention *other* effects that allow me to play additional permanents from the graveyard, but they don't address *the same* effect:

> *4/27/2018.* If multiple effects allow you to play a card from your graveyard, such as those of Gisa and Geralf and Karador, Ghost Chieftain, you must announce which permission you’re using as you begin to play the card.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Yes, You may play additional cards for each Muldrotha you control.**

From the Card specific rulings in Gatherer:

> If you play a card from your graveyard and then have a new Muldrotha
> come under your control in the same turn, you may play another card of
> that type from your graveyard that turn.
>
> If multiple effects allow you to play a card from your graveyard, such
> as those of Gisa and Geralf and Karador, Ghost Chieftain, you must
> announce which permission you’re using as you begin to play the card.

This is written under the assumption that you can only control one Muldrotha at a time, but it remains true if you control multiple Muldrothas. Each instance of Muldrotha only checks if you already played a permanent of the same type with the permisssion of that specific Muldrotha.

You may still only play one land per turn unless another effect states otherwise.

To be precise the rulings mention *multiple* effects, this includes other effects as well as multiple instances of the same effect. You will still have to announce which Muldrotha you are using for each card played.